# Error while sending POST request to WSO2 ESB

Tags: twitter, wso2, wso2-esb

I've created a proxy to tweet using **WSO2 ESB Twitter connector**. My Tweet proxy looks like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy name="Tweet" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
      transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <target>
        <inSequence>
          <property expression="json-eval($.message)" name="Tweet"
            scope="default" type="STRING"/>
          <twitter.init>
            <consumerKey>xxxxxxxxxx</consumerKey>
            <consumerSecret>xxxxxxxxxxxx</consumerSecret>
            <accessToken>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</accessToken>
            <accessTokenSecret>xxxxxxxxxx</accessTokenSecret>
          </twitter.init>
          <twitter.updateStatus>
            <status>{$ctx:Tweet}</status>
          </twitter.updateStatus>
          <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
      </target>
    </proxy>
```

The project was deployed without any errors but when ever i make a POST request to Tweet from Postman im getting an error status of **170** with a message **Missing required parameter: status**.
The Post request consist of a json like this.

```
 {"Content-Type":"application/json","payload":"{\"message\":\"Hellow WSO2 ESB!!!! #WSO2 #Test\"}"}
```

In the ESB sever console it gives an error like this

```
ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.message>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
```

Any particular reason why im getting this error?. How to overcome this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property expression like this.

```
expression="json-eval($.payload.message)"
```